# Firebase Auth: managing users with the Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have to write a firebase function that receives a JSON with a list of users and has to manage them with the following rules. For each user in the received list:

1. If the user is already registered (email/password) in firebase, I update it.
2. If the user is not registered yet, I create it
3. If a user is registered in firebase **but it's not present in the received list**, I disable it.

Now, I came up with the following solution: I iterate for each user in the received list. I call admin.auth().createUser() method so that if the user is not registered it will be created, otherwise the method throws an error and in the catch() block I call admin.auth().updateUser().
For the second part, I retrieve all the users registered with  admin.auth().listUsers() and for each of them I check whether it's present in the received list: if don't so, I disable it.
For some reason, the correctness of this solution is uncertain: sometimes it doesn't work at all, other times when I call the function once it doesn't work but the second time a call the function it works, idk why is that.
This only happens when I send to the function a lot of users (about 400). If I send only few users it works fine.
Could anyone suggest to me maybe a better solution?  Thanks a lot for your answer.

This is the function:

```
exports.addClients = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // fetch recevied list from payload
    var receivedClients = req.body.clients;

    // create or update user
    receivedClients.forEach(client => {
        admin.auth().createUser({
            uid: client.id,
            email: client.email,
            emailVerified: true,
            password: client.password,
        })
            .catch(err => {
                // update user
                admin.auth().updateUser(client.id, {
                    email: client.email
                }).catch(err => {
                    // error updating user
                    log("Error updating user: " + err);
                });
            })

    });
    // disabling users not present in the received list
    listUsers = await admin.auth().listUsers();
    userRecords = listUsers.users;
    userRecords.forEach(record => {
        if (!receivedClients.some(client => client.id === record.uid)) {
            // disable user
            admin.auth().updateUser(record.uid, {
                disabled: true
            })
                .catch(err => {
                        // error disabling user
                        log("Error disaling user: " + err);
                    });
        }
    });

    // send response
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

[image: Received json sample]

Comment: The main problem with the above code is the poor handling of promises. You're firing off a series of promises in `forEach` loops without really handling their final outcomes, and as a result there's no guarantee that any of them will complete. The function might terminate before your promises.

Comment: Your `listUsers()` solution is not going to work if you have a large number of users. It only fetches up to 1000 users. Even if you fix that, the solution is unlikely to scale to really large volumes of users. You will end up fetching a lot of data on the wire, and the function will be really slow to respond. You should ideally find a solution where the input json contains the UIDs that needs to be disabled, so you can only operate on them.

Comment: Hi @HiranyaJayathilaka, it looks like your comment contains actionable information. This is best posted as an answer rather than a comment!